# How can I craft Misc slot items?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How do you craft Misc slot items in TF2?  I have seen some players who have crafted miscs, but the only recipe I can find in TF2 is one that "builds headgear".

How does one craft a misc item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the name, the "Fabricate Headgear" and "Rebuild Headgear" crafting recipies can also produce misc items.

Source: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Random_crafting_recipes